# What is the difference between Doubling the value vs Doubling the Texture (Noise Texture Node)

Tags: shader-nodes

Beginner here. Need help on understanding the difference between the below set up. Why is that blender give me two different finish when I do 'double value' vs 'double texture node'?

First image is having one noise texture node set up. Having the Scale at 34, Detail at 30 and Roughness at 1.
[image]

Second image is having two noise texture set up, the values were separated compared to that of the first image.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The results are different simply because your two examples are telling Blender to perform completely different things - the Noise Texture cannot be split in that way to produce the same result.

In your first example you’re using the input coordinates (effectively Generated coordinates) to generate noise at a scale of 34 and roughness of 1. In your second example you’re using the input coordinates (the same as in the first example) to produce noise at a different scale but then using the output of that (which then won’t relate to the original coordinates) at yet another scale (the Scale represents the scale of the texture in texture space, not the **amount** of noise as you seem to assume).

This second example is effectively producing noise that varies based on the amount of noise from the first Noise, rather than on the position in the texture.